# VLC stream RTSP USB webcam

Tags: pi-3b+, webcam, vlc, rtsp

I'm trying to stream a usb camera using VLC. I used [this page](https://chriscarey.com/blog/2017/04/30/achieving-high-frame-rate-with-a-raspberry-pi-camera-system/comment-page-1/) to get it working on a pi zero with a raspberry pi camera attached to it.

On a second RPI 3B+ I'd like to do the same only with a USB camera. I can't seem to get it to work. I followed [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846400/raspberry-pi-use-vlc-to-stream-webcam-logitech-c920-h264-video-without-tran) for a logitec camera, but I only get errors:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=4,audio-sync=1}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,mime=video/ts,dst=:8099}'
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
[013c39e8] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[013c4d58] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[01347ce8] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[013c4d58] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1822:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
[7270db10] access_alsa demux error: cannot open ALSA device "hw:1,0": No such file or directory
[73600668] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[73600668] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'alsa://hw:1,0'. Check the log for details.
[72703280] main mux error: cannot add this stream
[7270e9b8] main decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (YUY2)
[7270e9b8] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks for your help.

Regards, Erik

Comment: what is the output of `arecord -l` as per the answer in your second link?